# How to search for Twitter lists?

Tags: twitter

Is there any possible way to search for Twitter lists on Twitter?

Let's say I want to find twitter lists regarding "social media experts". What would I do?

Answer (score 2):

Well, "social media expert twitter list" seems like a reasonable web search to me. Twitter's search just isn't up to this sort of task.

A better method, I think, is to take someone who you would expect to be on such a list and look at the lists they're currently on.

(Of course, the utility of such a list is debatable. [A year ago there were over 15k self-proclaimed social media experts on Twitter](http://mashable.com/2009/12/27/social-media-experts-twitter/).)

Comment: You can improve with `site:twitter.com inurl:list intext:"social media"` or `site:twitter.com bio "social media"`

Comment: Thanks! But to your remark: The example for "social media expert" was just something I came up with to explain more precisely what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Glick wrote me on Twitter, and I wanted to share his tip with you, in case you wonder about this too:

> @sebastianhoitz You can't. Try
>   tlists.com instead.

I found his tip to be pretty good.

http://twitter.com/jonathanglick/status/27041864966Blockquotetlists.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Mashable](http://mashable.com/) has a [Twitter list directory](http://mashable.com/twitterlists/).
There's [WeFollow](http://wefollow.com/), directory that associates Twitter users by self-proclaimed tags.

Oh, just found this [list of directories](http://www.jasonbartholme.com/21-twitter-directories-and-follower-finders-to-expand-your-twittersphere/).

Comment: WeFollow redirects to About.me. Does About.me have such a feature hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly (around 2012), Twitter allowed to search for lists in the advanced search (or facets of the search).

Nowadays, your best chance is IMHO to [perform an advanced search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=MYKEYWORD+site%3Atwitter.com+-site%3Adev.twitter.com+-site%3Ablog.twitter.com+inurl%3Alists+-inurl%3Amembers+-inurl%3Asubscribers). The results tend to be the most comprehensive and at the same time usually exclude complete garbage (which tends to have no incoming links and to be indexed poorly if at all).

From those lists, I usually find more lists via the profiles of the listed people, and so on. It's often hard to find a good "connector" user who brings you to all lists.